# load django form template with Jquery

Tags: jquery, django

I want to load a form of a django template in a Jquery popup. The form loads fine in the popup's div but when i click submit nothing happens. The form itself seems to work on it's own url but not in the popup of the other page where i try to load it.
Someone know whats the Problem im pretty new to django and jquery.

The form i want to load into the popup:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

My Jquery:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    var button = $('#button');
    button.click(function(){
        $('#newsletter').load('/newsletter #newsletterform').css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```

My Views:

```
def newsletter(request):
    recipients = Recipient.objects.order_by('adress')
    return render(request, 'newsletter/adress_list.html', {'recipients':recipients})

def add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewsletterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            recipient = form.save(commit=False)
            recipient.save()
            return redirect('/join')
    else:
        form = NewsletterForm()
    return render(request, 'newsletter/add.html', {'form': form})
```

My Newsletter App URLs:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^list/$', views.newsletter),
    url(r'^$', views.add, name='add'),
)
```

Django-CMS Url:

```
url(r'^newsletter/', include('newsletter.urls',
```

Comment: What error do you get? Also, what URL is the form supposed to submit to? You're loading it from a different URL...but then processing it in the current URL?

Comment: Set the action parameter of the form to the url you want the form to post to.

Comment: No error its just the content of the form is not saved to the list like it usual does. I think it cant work because of the URL thing

Comment: when i set action to: `action="{% url newsletter %}"`. Form no longer appears in the popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `action` of the form to point to your other URL/view. Assuming your `add` view exists at the `/newsletter` URL, you would change your form to:

```
<form action="/newsletter" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: ok this works perfect, made some mistakes by integrating my app to django-cms